# How to update custom button/menu/group icon on the fly?

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to put alignment buttons (left, center, right, justify) behind a single button in the TinyMCE v6 toolbar. I know that I can use `editor.ui.registry.addSplitButton()` to define the button with a static icon with properties `text: "", title: "Text alignment menu", icon: "..."`.

However, I would want the menu icon to reflect the current status. When text caret is moved in left aligned text, I'd want he menu icon to have the left-aligned text icon and when text caret is moved to centered text, the icon should have centered text icon. And the button action should toggle *that* alignment on and off and the split feature would allow changing the alignment further.

However, I cannot see anything to dynamically change the menu button in TinyMCE v6. How to change the split button icon in the toolbar when caret is moved?

(I'm looking for a generic answer where the menu opened with the button could also contain additional items to the default alignment options, too.)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27862988/334451 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/41873321/334451

Comment: Current related documentation: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/typesoftoolbarbuttons/#basicbuttonexampleandexplanation